# Application rejected for crashing on an iPad 3rd Generation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, crash

My app was rejected by Apple because its crash on iPad 3rd Gen.
Rejected reason:

> We found that your app crashed on iPad 3rd Gen. running iOS 5.1.1, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Your app crashed on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks on launch.

I tested my app on iPhone 4 both simulator and device and its work fine, I also tested the app on iPad simulator both iPad and iPad retina simulator and its work fine.
But I don't have an actual iPad 3rd Gen device.
here is the code for application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

//Piracy Check
iShmoopi *PiracyCheck = [[[iShmoopi alloc] init] autorelease];
if ([PiracyCheck isPirated] == KAPPLICATIONNOTPIRATED || [PiracyCheck isPirated] == KNOTPIRATED) {
    //Do Nothing, Not Pirated
} else {
    //Do Something, Pirated
    
    //Hostile Exit 
    iShmoopi *HostileExit = [[[iShmoopi alloc] init] autorelease];
    [HostileExit Hostile];
}


NSString *gameDataPath = pathInDocumentDirectory(@"gameDataPath.data");
if (gameDataPath != nil) {
    
    NSDictionary *gameDataDictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:gameDataPath];
    
    if  (gameDataDictionary != nil) {
    
        smartEasyBestTime = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"smartEasyBestTimeKey"] intValue];
        smartEasyBestPoint = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"smartEasyBestPointKey"] intValue];
        smartNormalIsPlayable = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"smartNormalIsPalyableKey"] boolValue];
        smartNormalBestTime = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"smartNormalBestTimeKey"] intValue];
        smartNormalBestPoint = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"smartNormalBestpointKey"] intValue];
        smartHardIsPlayable = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"smartHardIsPalyableKey"] boolValue];
        smartHardBestTime = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"smartHardBestTimeKey"] intValue];
        smartHardBestPoint = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"smartHardBestPointKey"] intValue];
        
        focusEasyBestTime = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"focusEasyBestTimeKey"] intValue];
        focusEasyBestPoint = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"focusEasyBestPointKey"] intValue];
        focusNormalIsPlayable = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"focusNormalIsPalyableKey"] boolValue];
        focusNormalBestTime = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"focusNormalBestTimeKey"] intValue];
        focusNormalBestPoint = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"focusNormalBestpointKey"] intValue];
        focusHardIsPlayable = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"focusHardIsPalyableKey"] boolValue];
        focusHardBestTime = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"focusHardBestTimeKey"] intValue];
        focusHardBestPoint = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"focusHardBestPointKey"] intValue];
        
        logicEasyBestTime = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"logicEasyBestTimeKey"] intValue];
        logicEasyBestPoint = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"logicEasyBestPointKey"] intValue];
        logicNormalIsPlayable = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"logicNormalIsPalyableKey"] boolValue];
        logicNormalBestTime = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"logicNormalBestTimeKey"] intValue];
        logicNormalBestPoint = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"logicNormalBestpointKey"] intValue];
        logicHardIsPlayable = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"logicHardIsPalyableKey"] boolValue];
        logicHardBestTime = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"logicHardBestTimeKey"] intValue];
        logicHardBestPoint = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"logicHardBestPointKey"] intValue];
        
        speedEasyBestTime = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"speedEasyBestTimeKey"] intValue];
        speedEasyBestPoint = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"speedEasyBestPointKey"] intValue];
        speedNormalIsPlayable = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"speedNormalIsPalyableKey"] boolValue];
        speedNormalBestTime = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"speedNormalBestTimeKey"] intValue];
        speedNormalBestPoint = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"speedNormalBestpointKey"] intValue];
        speedHardIsPlayable = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"speedHardIsPalyableKey"] boolValue];
        speedHardBestTime = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"speedHardBestTimeKey"] intValue];
        speedHardBestPoint = [[gameDataDictionary objectForKey:@"speedHardBestPointKey"] intValue];
    }
}

self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


return YES;

}
```

and this is the code for the first view controller loaded

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

//Piracy Check
iShmoopi *PiracyCheck = [[[iShmoopi alloc] init] autorelease];
if ([PiracyCheck isPirated] == KAPPLICATIONNOTPIRATED || [PiracyCheck isPirated] == KNOTPIRATED) {
    //Do Nothing, Not Pirated
    NSLog(@"not pirated");
} 
else 
{
    //Do Something, Pirated
    
    //Hostile Exit 
    iShmoopi *HostileExit = [[[iShmoopi alloc] init] autorelease];
    [HostileExit Hostile];
}

[titleImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gameTitleImage.png"]];

NSTimer *t;
t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(tEnd) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

By the way I use [Shmoopi Anti-Piracy Library](http://www.shmoopi.net/shmoopiantipiracy/) that shown above in the code.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Suggestion: use the internet to find a tester with the device and analyse crash log. In the company I work for we've been dealing with devices and simulators since times of iOS 2.2.1, and I assure you that simulator testing is **not** enough. Ever. Also make sure your iPhone 4 devices uses iOS 5.1.1, and does not crash.

Comment: I tested my app on iPhone 4 run iOS 5.1.1 and its work just fine. Also i will consider finding a tester on the internet. thanks for replay.

Comment: Solution: spend less time protecting against piracy and instead spend more time making a quality application.

Comment: Is it possible that something on Apple's test device triggered your piracy countermeasures?

Comment: thank you all for respond, i will try changing the piracy code and submit my app again

Comment: I cannot believe someone "down voted" this question.  This is a serious problem and Apple needs to fix the fact their simulator works fine and the device crashes.  I got the same rejection notice and I'm not using this anti-piracy stuff so give Abdullah.th a break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My app has been approved.
I deleted Shmoopi Anti-Piracy Library code and write my own.
So the problem was that Shmoopi Anti-Piracy Library is not compatible with iPad 3rd Gen.

Answer (score 1):

Find a way to test in a real device. Borrow, rent or buy one.

Comment: Uncool answer.  I have an iPad 1 and 2.  Buying a 3rd iPad just to release my iPhone app.  Come on.  Can someone really answer this question by stating some of the differences and why the sim works the device does not?  Why isn't the apple test center giving us crash logs.

Comment: Yeah that stinks. I understand. But really in the end, the only way to be sure is to test on that device. Is there someone you know you can borrow one from or at least sit with for a while so you can do some testing?

Comment: So is it safe to sell the older iPads and just get the 3rd gen?